# Capture specific first matches in regex

Tags: regex

I have this text and want to capture each match of the letter '`ñ`' under the html `href` attribute. I want it to match the '`ñ`' in both `niño.html` and `niña.html`, but not the ones in `Niño` and `Niña`:

```
<a href='niño.html'>Niño</a> <a href='niña.html'>Niña</a>
```

I tried this but it also matches `Niño`:

```
ñ(.*?\.html'>)+?
```

When replacing with `n\1`, it gives:

```
<a href='nino.html'>Nino</a> <a href='niña.html'>Niña</a>
```

What I would want the text to look like is:

```
<a href='nino.html'>Niño</a> <a href='nina.html'>Niña</a>
```

How can I do this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1848654 - Use an HTML parser.

Comment: What language/tool are you using?  You might want to use an HTML parser here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when you try this the part between does not contain the single quote:

```
ñ([^']*?\.html'>)+?
```